# openSSL and gnuTLS can't connect to OpenWRT web interface, why not?

Tags: ssl, openwrt

I have some weirdness securely connecting to OpenWRT from IceWeasel (debian Firefox).  I find recent Firefox's error messages less useful for troubleshooting.

So I want some HTTPS tool to run tests on the connection.  But my usual command-line tools were failing completely.  Why?  Is this a known bug?

```
$ curl --insecure https://mortar.local
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

$ wget --no-check-certificate https://mortar.local
--2014-10-02 10:42:53--  https://mortar.local/
Resolving mortar.local (mortar.local)... 10.209.37.18
Connecting to mortar.local (mortar.local)|10.209.37.18|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

The above is on Debian 7.6.  wget and curl were respectively using gnutls26 2.12.20-8+deb7u2`and openssl 1.0.1e-2+deb7u12.

If I switch to Fedora 20, curl works but not wget.  On Fedora wget still uses openssl, but curl uses NSS 3.16.2, so I can use that for the tests I originally wanted to run.  IceWeasel/Firefox uses NSS, so it explains why IceWeasel doesn't always fail.  But I don't like that there's an incompatibility with the other two SSL libraries.

```
OpenWRT 12.09
uhttpd-mod-tls 2012-10-30-e57bf6d8bfa465a50eea2c30269acdfe751a46fd
libcyassl 1.6.5-1
```

Update: also applies to OpenWRT 14.07

Comment: If you could provide a packet dump of successful connections (NSS) vs. unsuccessful (gnutls, openssl) one could maybe see a pattern. From my understanding browsers try to downgrade the ssl version on connection problems while non-browsers do not. But I don't know if this is specific to browsers or a feature of NSS so that curl+NSS retries too.

Answer (score 0):

Update x2: I retested from Debian 7 system, and both curl and wget work now.  I haven't seen a weird problem with IceWeasel (Firefox) yet either.  Crypto libraries are now openssl 1.0.1e-2+deb7u14 and gnutls 2.12.20-8+deb7u2.  That's no change in gnutls (and OpenWRT doesn't do automatic updates).

So I really don't know why curl (using gnutls) is working now.  Nor do I have anything to troubleshoot.

The strongest hypothesis is: perhaps there was a bug which OpenWRT 14.07 fixed - however I know my upgrade to 14.07 wasn't very smooth, so that could have left a weird problem.

Gory details - I had managed to upgrade the squashfs image (read-only base filesystem), while leaving the package source configured for 12.09 & a bunch of packages installed from there on the JFFS overlay.  That took a bunch of fixing.  I should probably save my config files and package list and re-flash, in case there's anything *else* lurking :).